# How to compute equation that includes a^n / n! for large a and/or n?

Tags: numerical-methods

I'm trying to compute

$$e^{-a} \times \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{a^n}{n!}$$

where $e^{1}=2.7183$, `N` is an integer > 0, and `a` is a real value > 0. For example, `N=a=1500`.

But for large n, the n! goes to infinity, and for large a, the numerator a^n goes to infinity. Can any tricks be applied to compute this? What about in the case of either a>n or a< n?

UPDATE

Based on @DavidK answer, could I get extra precision by taking the log of the expression? For example, the natural log of the above expression is:

$$-a + log(\sum_{n=0}^N \frac{a^n}{n!})$$

then when I get a result from this expression, take its inverse natural log? If so, the problem boils down how to compute

$$log(\sum_{n=0}^N \frac{a^n}{n!})$$

without overflow (any ideas?).

Comment: Don't compute $a^n$ and $n!$ separately. Compute the terms as in $({a \over n} )( {a \over n-1}) \cdots ({a \over 1})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any real number $a$ and for any $N \geq 0$ the product 
$$e^{-a} \times \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{a^n}{n!},$$
that is, the ideal mathematical object that your computation is
apparently supposed to represent, is a positive real number.
For $N=0$ the value of the product is simply $e^{-a}$, but as you
add terms (that is, for larger and larger $N$) the product approaches $1$,
but is always at least a tiny bit smaller.

If you have used the expression `exp(-a)` in an attempt to represent $e^{-a}$,
and the result of that expression is zero, it is not possible to get the
correct result by computing the sum. That is, there is no number you
could set the sum equal to, which, when multiplied by zero,
would give you a result that is a positive number less than or equal to $1$.

So the difficulty occurs not because your computation of the sum overflows.
The difficulty occurs because your computation of $e^{-a}$ underflows.

If you use a floating-point representation capable of representing
$e^{-a}$ as a normalized non-zero value (that is, a value that may be very
small, but is sufficiently different from zero that the computer can
store it without losing too many digits of precision),
then the sum should not overflow when you try to compute it.

---

**Edit:** copper.hat's technique is a relatively well-known way to add up terms when each term is a known multiple of the previous one.
You *may* be able to use logarithms with an adaptation of that technique 
to make a reasonably accurate calculation of your desired product where
$e^{-a}$ would underflow.

Using the method *without* logarithms, you might compute a sequence of
values like this:

\begin{align}
x_0 &= \frac{a}{N} \\
x_1 &= \frac{a}{N - 1}(1 + x_0) \\
x_2 &= \frac{a}{N - 2}(1 + x_1) \\
    & \quad \vdots \\
x_i &= \frac{a}{N - i}(1 + x_{i-1}) \\
    & \quad \vdots \\
x_{N-1} &= \frac{a}{1}(1 + x_{N-2}) \\
x_N &= 1 + x_{N-1} \\
\end{align}

The problem is that for very large $a$, the sequence grows very quickly
near the end, and may overflow your chosen numeric type if you do this
in a typical programming language without special "large number" support.
So instead you can work with the sequence $y_0, \ldots, y_N$ defined by
$y_i = \log(x_i)$.
Assuming $\log$ is natural log, 
you can use the fact that $1 + x = x\left(1 + \frac 1x\right)$ to rewrite

\begin{align}
\log(x_i) &= \log\left(\frac{a}{N - i}(1 + x_{i-1})\right) \\
&= \log(a) - \log(N - i) + \log(x_{i-1}) + \log\left(1 + \frac 1{x_{i-1}}\right)
\end{align}
as
$$
y_i = \log(a) - \log(N - i) + y_{i-1} + \log(1 + \exp(-y_{i-1})).
$$

Let $y_0 = \log(a/N)$, use the formula above to compute $y_i$
for $i = 1, 2, \ldots, N - 1$, and finally let
$y_N = y_{N-1} + \log(1 + \exp(-y_{N-1})).$

At some point during this computatation, if $a$ and $N$ are both large
enough, $\exp(-y_{i-1})$ will underflow, with the result that
$\log(1 + \exp(-y_{i-1}))$ will evaluate to $0$ rather than to
its correct (but very small) value.
This is a bias toward underestimating the sum,
but since $\log(1 + \exp(-y_{i-1})) < \exp(-y_{i-1})$,
and since $\exp(-y_{i-1})$ will be tiny and (probably)
very rapidly decreasing at that point,
the bias may not be too much.

At the end, you can evaluate your product, using the fact that
$$y_N = \log\left(\sum_{n=0}^N \frac{a^n}{n!}\right).$$

Comment: your analysis is correct. Sometimes, however, the summation overflows before $e^{−a}$ underflows. Thus, couldn't I do something like take the log of the expression, that is $log(e^{-a})=−a$ and add it to the log of the summation, then take the inverse log of the result? The problem then is how to take the log of the summation. I updated the original question to raise this possibility.

Comment: The log of the summation is indeed where the difficulty would occur. I have added some thoughts to the end of the answer about how to deal with that calculation.

Comment: By the way, I was counting denormalized values as a kind of "underflow"; that is, with IEEE-754 the exponent of $10$ in a positive number can be much more negative than it can be positive, but the most negative powers are achieved by discarding bits of precision, so really by the time the sum will have overflowed, $e^{-a}$ will have too little precision to be useful as a factor even if it has not underflowed all the way to zero. But it all leads to needing some other way to deal with very large numbers (e.g. logarithms) anyway.

Comment: Thanks @DavidK, is $y_n$ as you show above (e.g. the log of the summed terms) equal to $y_N$? In other words, is that a typo (should $y_n$ really be written $y_N$)? If not, how to relate the two?

Comment: Indeed, that was a typo, as you suspected. Oops! I have corrected it.

Comment: Great, this really REALLY helped @DavidK, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Note that 
$\sum_{n=0}^N {a^n \over n!} = 1+ {a \over 1} (1+{a\over 2}(1+\cdots{a \over N-1}(1+ {a \over N}))\cdots))$.

Comment: Thanks, your comment above (in the original posting) seems more intuitive for me to program in a loop for each n, then sum over n=0 to N.

Comment: Thanks @copper.hat, I'm running into the problem where the summation exceeds the max double precision value. Since `a` is > 1, I tried moving the `exp(-a)` into the summation to reduce the terms that get summed, which helped a little, but still I'm exceeding the limit. Could I do a `log` somewhere to complete the math then do an `anti-log` at the end?

Comment: @user46688 Unless the double-precision representation of `exp(-a)` is zero or denormal, `exp(a)` should be representable in double precision, and so should all the terms in your sum, which is just a partial sum of a series representation of $e^a$. Note that multiplication by a denormal results in loss of precision, so you really should not be doing this calculation if all the terms can't be represented in your chosen floating-point precision. Perhaps you should consider quadruple precision.

Comment: @DavidK, yes `exp(-a)` is zero when the summation goes to infinity. I'm coding in Javascript. I haven't heard the term `denormal` before... are you referring to the `log` discussion? As an example: `a=1512`, `N=30` yields 0; but `a=1512`, `N=300` yields NaN.

Comment: You will need more than double precision, even if denormalised, to represent $e^{1512}$.

Comment: @copper.hat, that should be `exp(-1512)` which is 0. What goes to infinity is the multiplication of terms shown in your  comment above in the original post.

Comment: Well, the summation converges to $e^a$, so either you are computing (something close to) $e^a$ or $e^{-a}$, so you **will** run into precision issues. The correct answer (in infinite precision) is 1 in the limit, of course.

Comment: Is this for a numerical methods class? Are they trying to illustrate an issue or have you solve it?

Comment: Interesting problem.

Comment: I had more to say than would fit in a comment, and it seemed actually to be a possibly useful answer, so I wrote it as one. You might want to ask the real-life problem that inspired this question as another question. (If you do, link to the new question in a comment on this question so we'll be alerted.)

Comment: Did I say something wrong?

Comment: Nope, I'm just re-evaluating based on the 2 new answers, as I haven't solved this yet, although your answer was the best as of yesterday. Wish I could give out +1 for your comments individually but I have to wait for more reputation points apparently.

Comment: No problem, just curious :-).

Comment: You've been awesome, thanks.

Comment: You might add to the question the size of $a$ you are interested in (as in $a=1512$).

Comment: Done, thanks...

Comment: It occurred to me that since I ended up using the formula from this answer as the starting point for the second half of my answer, this answer deserves some credit too, so +1.

Answer (score 0):

From its definition,
you are guaranteed that,
if $a > 0$,
$e^{-a}  \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{a^n}{n!}
\le 1
$.
(If $a < 0$
and $|a|$ is large,
the sum will have catastrophic cancellation,
so there is a problem from the start.)

Therefore,
have your current expression
be of the form
$t_k
=e^{-m}s_k
$,
where 
$s_k
= \sum_{n=0}^k \frac{a^n}{n!}
$.

Initially,
$k=0$,
$m = 0$,
and
$s_k = 1
$.

Each time
$k$ is incremented,
and the new
$s_k$
and $t_k$
are computed,
check if
$t_k > 1
$.
If so,
increment $m$
until
$t_k
=e^{-m}s_k
\le 1
$.

Once $k = N$,
compare $m$ with $a$.
If
$m \ne a$,
multiply by
$e^{m-a}$.
This will guarantee that
you will never get overflows
(though
$\frac{a^n}{n!}$
might get small for
$n >> a$,
but that is another problem).

A problem with this
is that
the many multiplies by $\frac1{e}$
to get
$e^{-m}$
might cause roundoff error
to accumulate.
This can be alleviated
by techniques such as
precomputed tables for
$e^{-j}$.